# Powershell - CreateFromDirectory with excluding some types of file

Tags: powershell, zip

I am using a compress method

> [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)

but i need to exclude some specific file types - like .mp3, .mkv, .avi and such. Unfortunately i wasn't able to find a way how to do that :-(. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an application which allows you more flexible archiving from the command line, such as 7-Zip.

Alternately, if you insist on scripting your own solution, use Get-ChildItem, filter out the undesireables, and then iterate over the results and build the archive manually using System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.  That seems potentially pretty error prone to me, however.